# Is 'own' appropriate for an email address?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I recently used "I own some.email@gmail.com", and a friend said this was incorrect. I can see logically how this is true, you wouldn't use own in the context of an account identifier in any other circumstances (e.g. "I own 07700 123456"), but I can't think of a better word. Here's the full context:

> I own some.email@gmail.com from a project *waaaay* back. I get interesting emails occasionally, where someone has decided to test their product with that email address, not realising it's real and that I'm checking it.

Comment: I don't see why not. What did your friend suggest instead?

Comment: 'Have' was suggested, but it's more a case of 'own' being incorrect (and the sentence needing rewording) than something else being correct.

Comment: It's certainly possible to own non-material things, if that's the problem.

Comment: Thinking about it, the concept of ownership probably stems from the idea of an email address as an identity, something for which the word 'own' is appropriate.

Comment: While the address is non-material, the e-mail account and the storage space used are. Address and account are used as synonyms, comparable to a house and its address... cf my answer below :)

Comment: @Translator1983 I don't own the account though (although I do own my data), Google does.

Comment: I am with fredley on this. @gmail.com addresses are owned by Google, who can withdraw the service or close the account anytime they want. If you have a gmail account, you are a user, not an owner.  Think of the email addresses given to students or company employees. When they leave the university/employer, they cannot take the address with them because they do not own it.

Comment: @RoaringFish My house ownership example was a bit too strong. Nonetheless, the English word "to own" does _not_ only express "to have or possess as property"! According to the American Heritage Dictionary ([1b](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/own)), it also (equally!) means "to have control over". The amount of control you have over an e-mail account varies depending on who hosts it - you can even host it yourself if you know how. Nonetheless, you own it. The AH Dictionary (see link above) gives an example for potentially very brief ownership: "For a time, enemy planes owned the skies."

Comment: @RoaringFish Please, remember that the title is the actual question, the rest is merely an explanation. You know that, you are a more experienced user than me. The actual question is: *Is 'own' appropriate for an email address?* That is what I replied to and am talking about here. Please stay objective.

Comment: A title is just a title, and not choosing to ignore the context and example given by the OP, just because it is convenient to do so, *is* being objective...

Answer (score 2):

"Own" could be considered incorrect on the basis that you do not have ultimate control of a hosted email account. In the case of Gmail, Google could cancel the service or revoke the name without consulting you.

Having said that, the use of "own" is probably just a bit strong for the context it is being used.

Rather than:

> I own some.email@gmail.com from a project waaaay back.

... you could still show possession but more in line with the tone of the conversation:

- some.email@gmail.com is mine from a project waaaay back.

... or more relaxed still:

- I still have some.email@gmail.com from a project waaaay back.

Comment: Those are some good alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

One of the meaning of *own* (as verb) is "have something as one's own," and I think it applies in this case: Email addresses are unique in the same domain; if you have xyzabc@gmail.com as email, nobody else can have the same email, even if they could have xyzabc@yahoo.com.

Answer (score 1):

Common parlance for web domains and email addresses is that you are ***sitting on*** it.  This phrase has the added implication that you are not currently using it.

Answer (score 0):

After examining the word **[own](http://www.onelook.com/?w=own&ls=a)** in the dictionary, I'll discuss a dissenting opinion, and concede he has a point.  When *own* is used as an adjective, it means something belongs to a certain individual, but when *own* is used as a verb, it means *to possess*.

[image]

Sure, it's *your* email account; you alone use it, and you alone know the password. But technically, I think the account is owned by Google, not you.  (If Google shut down gmail tomorrow, the account would vanish, and you wouldn't have any recourse).  So, maybe it would have been more precise to refer to the account by saying *"my own some.email account"* (using *own* as an adjective) rather than saying *"I own the some.email account"* (using *own* as a verb).

In the end, this becomes a somewhat technical matter of ownership and possession in the virtual realm.  You might own a domain name (because you're paying for it), but do you own a free account?  Or does the host own it, and you merely use it?

All that said, it's a bit of a grey area, and some might argue that he's being overly picky and too rigid in his adherence to the strict dictionary definition.

In the end, I think I'd side with you and against your friend on this one.  If to *own* means to *possess*, what does *possess* mean?  NOAD says that *possess* means *have as belonging to one*.  I would argue the account *belongs* to you, and therefore you *own* it.

Comment: Even in the case of a domain or self hosted email system, it's technically owned by the *service provider* not the user.

Comment: ... and note that the individual with the email address is a *user*, not an *owner*.

Comment: In German, there is a distinctive (legal) difference between "Eigentum" and "Besitz", the former with you as the sole+permanent owner, the second with you as the one that possesses/lives in it. In English, _to own_ or _to possess_ are most commonly used for something that you bought or received, but do not exclude things that you only have temporary control over. If something is your *property*, then you can be sure that you are the only owner. If you rent something, you own/possess it, but not permanently. Depending on a country's laws, you can have very extensive rights over what you rent.

Comment: The house is owned by the person who holds the deeds. The person who holds the deeds is almost invariably the person who paid the mortgage. The individual paying the rent is, by definition, not the owner. *Own* and *possess*, btw, are not synonymous. [OED: Possess: To have possession of, as distinct from ownership (see possession n. 1b); esp. to hold or occupy as a tenant, to lease.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148345?rskey=vQys0t&result=1#eid)

Comment: Dictionary definitions: M-W *own* [a: to have or hold as property: possess; b: to have power or mastery over] *possess* [a: to have and hold as property: own]*; DCE *possess* [2 *formal or law* to have or own something]...

Comment: @RoaringFish: For the record, I never said that _own_ and _possess_ were synonymous, I merely pointed out that the dictionary does list "possess" as a meaning of "own" ~ see screen shot; I don't make this stuff up ;^)

Comment: @Noah: I agree with you, and even had that thought; I only meant to point out that the waters become even muddier when currency is changing hands. (Oh, can I say "change hands" if no one touches the money?  This language stuff gets tricky sometimes...)

Comment: @J.R. The comment by RF was actually just intended to discredit my comment and not to reply to your answer. We had something of a battle of words in all comment sections of this question here from which I am backing out since there is no end in sight.

Comment: @Translator1983: Oh. You should upvote the question then, if you haven't already. (By default, anything that generates such a spirited discussion is bound to own some degree of quality – but that's just my opinion.) P.S. "discredit" is a rather harsh word, don't you think? RoaringFish (or anyone else) can respectfully take an opposing stance in a debate. Sometimes on EL&U, two users eventually have to "agree to disagree" – no harm intended on either side; and one of them doesn't need to own the other by the time the debate ends.

Comment: @J.R. I fully agree. I upvoted and favorited the question. I learned a lot from this topic, although I still disagree with the general consensus and feel that Mr. Fish did, indeed, try to "own" me ;)

Answer (score -1):

While the *address* itself is public, the *account* and the *password* needed to use the address are yours.

If the e-mail **account** is yours, it "belongs" to you and you "own" it. 
The account is always identified by its address.

**Yes, you own (*the gmail account*) some.email@gmail.com.**

You can compare it to owning a house: The house number is yours as well. 
In a conversation, you will either say "I own the house in 5 Drury Lane" or "I own 5 Drury Lane", where "the house on" is implied.

Comment: But I *don't* own it in that sense. I've agreed to some T&C's with Google to use it, but I don't own it any more than the house I live in (which I rent).

Comment: @fredley Good news for you: You _own_ your rented house, because it is yours as long as you live there, and the actual _owner_ of the house has relinquished a part of his rights to the house to you temporarily! He can have you evicted (under certain circumstances), he can ask you to let him into the house, but if he enters it without your permission, he is breaking the law. While Google reserves extensive rights to your data and account, not all providers do. You can even host your website and e-mail account on your own computer if you rent (and thus own) a domain name!

Comment: Maybe the law is different where you are, but in no way do I own my house!

Comment: @fredley It's more a matter of language than law: The verbs "to own" and "to possess" only mean that you have something, not that you have the exclusive right to do with it as you please. For that, it would have to be your *property*. You "own" a car even if it is not fully paid yet and still officially belongs to the bank that gave you the loan. As a drug courier, you can be caught possessing (or in the possession of) drugs, even if they belong to the cartel. Simply put, if something is "your own", you own it as long as no one takes it from you, whether taking it is lawful or not.

Comment: @fredley ~ I agree. You are either renting a house or you own a house, you cannot do both. At least not in any country I am aware of. The 'own=control' argument doesn't work. If you are renting you cannot sell the house, sub-let, extend, alter, instal new windows or central heating, fit a new kitchen or new windows, etc. You do not have control of the property, but the owner (the individual that owns it...) does.

Comment: @RoaringFish: For a house, the difference between _renting_ and _owning_ is pretty clear.  For an email account, though, there might be some room to bend the word _own_ a little bit. After all, the dictionary doesn't restrict the word to cases where someone has clear title or deed over some piece of property or material object, although that may be a valid _legal_ interpretation of the word. "To have (something) as one's own" seems to have some inherent wiggle room, at least in my mind.

Comment: The house makes clear the distinction between ownership and simply making use of something. I agree with you that ownership goes beyond holding title, and if I were pressed on it I would probably come up with something based on unrestricted control. In practice that usually goes with payment, but not exclusively. I own a few library books that somehow never got returned (moved house... you know how it is) but I consider that I now own them because I have unrestrictewd control over those books. This is why I dispute owning an email address - the service provider has most of the control.

Comment: @RoaringFish: All well and good, and I wouldn't call anyone "wrong" for taking that stance.  All the same, the person who "owns" the email account does have some measure of control – setting display options, changing the password, designating blocked addresses – so I wouldn't dogmatically aver that using the word "own" is entirely wrong, either.  After studying the dictionary definitions and mulling this over, my personal opinion is that such usage lands squarely in a gray area, and that either stance can be reasonably justified.